# Planck's Law. It's $E=hf$ or $E=nhf$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, discrete

My textbook provides intuition of Planck's Quantum theory which is copied right next.

> Max Planck proposed that emission or absorption of energy in a blackbody is discontinuous. It is absorbed or emitted in packets $hf$ or integral multiple of these packets $nhf$. Each packet is called Quantum.
>
> Energy lost or gained is given by;
>
> $E=hf$ where $f$ is the frequency of radiations.

I think the equation which is consistent with the definition above is E=nhf. If not, please explain which thing I am missing.

I have searched it on internet but explanation is given in terms of photon however I want to understand how does $E=hf$ is consistent with the brief description given in my book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $E = hf$ is the energy of each packet or photon. So if $n$ photons are emitted, the total energy is $E = nhf$.

Comment: Does that mean that a blackbody may release several packets of energy at a time?

Comment: @SufyanNaeem Yes. A blackbody emits electromagnetic radiation of a particular wavelength depending on the temperature of the body. The higher temperature a body has, the higher the frequency of these emitted packets of energy(photons) will be which determines the $f$ in Planck's law and $n$ is the number of photons emitted. You can calculate the total lost energy by determining the photon energy density.

Comment: @Starior if an electron emits or absorb radiation of frequency "f" then it would either be demoted or promoted . The energy difference between the orbits, it made transition between, should be given by; $$\delta {E} = nhf$$. But my book states it is given by; $$\delta {E} = hf$$ Explain please.

Comment: @SufyanNaeem Note that every single electron would emit radiation with an energy of $$E = hf$$ but the total lost energy would be $$E = nhf$$. Therefore, since one electron emits radiation with an energy of $$E = hf$$, the energy difference between the initial and final orbit would be $$\delta {E} = hf$$ as your book states.

Comment: @Starior That means an electron can absorb or emit only a single packet of energy but each packet depends upon the frequency it is thrown with. Is that so?

Comment: @SufyanNaeem Yes, you can make that statement at an elementary level. However, as I stated above to calculate the total energy lost or absorbed by a blackbody, you may need to determine the photon energy density which is governed by Bose-Einstein distribution function.

Comment: Then it is going to work because I am indeed studying it on elementary level.